# How can i solve this: 'NameError: name 'outpt_attr' is not defined'

Tags: python

When i run the input placeQuad(-0.9,-0.4,1.0), i keep getting this error  'NameError: name 'outpt_attr' is not defined'. any help will be highly appreciated:
code is below;

```
pt1= Point(0,0)
circle=pt1.buffer(1)
##collection of point and a circle

circle_pt1=collection([pt1,circle])
circle_pt1
# indentify qaud boundaries
def placeQuad(x,y,r):
    circle = Point(0,0).buffer(1)

### creating quadrants
    q1 = Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(0,0)]).intersection(circle)
    q2 = Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(0,0)]).intersection(circle)
    q3 = Polygon([(0,0),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(0,-1),(0,0)]).intersection(circle)
    q4 = Polygon([(0,0),(0,-1),(1,-1),(1,0),(0,0)]).intersection(circle)
    
### storing the quadrants into a dictionary
    quadrants = {"Quad1":q1, "Quad2":q2, "Quad3":q3, "Quad4":q4}
    
    pt = Point(x,y)
    outQuadrants = dict()
    for key, quadrant in quadrants.items():
        if pt.intersects(quadrant):
            print ("point ({},{}) plots inside Quadrant {}".format(x,y,key))
          
    else:
        outQuadrants.update({key:quadrant})  

       ###outer quadrants

    if len(outQuadrants) == 4:
        global outpt_attr 
        outpt_attr= dict()  
        
    for key, quadrant in outQuadrants.items():
        center_dist = pt.distance(quadrant.centroid)
        arc_dist = pt.distance(quadrant)
        outpt_attr.update({key: [round(center_dist,2), round(arc_dist,2)]})
 
        print ("pt({},{}) plots outside {}. Distance to closest point on arc is {:.2f}, \
                   while distance to centre of quadrant is {}".format())
```

##input values
placeQuad(-0.9,-0.4,1.0)

Comment: You only set `outpt_attr` when `len(outQuadrants) == 4`. But you only update `outQuadrants` once, in the `else:` block of `for key, quadrant in quadrants.items():`, so the length is 1.

Comment: BTW, when you're just setting one property, use an assignment instead of `update()`: `outQuadrants[key] = quadrant`

Comment: Did you intend for that to be the `else:` block of `if` rather than `for`? You need to indent it another level.

Comment: still not working

Comment: What is `len(outQuadrants)`?

Comment: Why is the initialization of `outpt_attr` only inside the `if` block? You use that variable in the next `for` loop even if the len is not 4.

Comment: I think you need to step back and figure out your general logic. I don't understand what you're trying to do.